# DROP DATABASE Recovery

Tags: mysql

I need to fix a problem. I have dropped a database. I have restored the `*.frm` and `*.ibd` files.

I haven't copied them into the mysql folder yet - can I just copy the files back and bring the server back up ?

`ibdata1`, `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` are still intact from when I quit the server with a `kill -9` in a panic.

What's the best way to proceed - I haven't tried anything yet as I was worried I might lose the data (if it's not lost already).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dropped a table with innodb_file_per_table ON it's better not to undelete the .ibd file, but rather scan the disk partition with page_parser from [percona data recovery toolkit](https://launchpad.net/percona-data-recovery-tool-for-innodb).

The ibd files after most certainly corrupt and you won't be able to IMPORT TABLESPACE. Another problem is undelete tools usually (every time I've seen actually) misses chunks of data for sake of reconstructing a file.

To quickly check what's inside the undeleted ibd and see how many records lost/recovered I can suggest https://recovery.twindb.com (DISCLAIMER - I'm the author). But, again, I'd parse the partition.

Comment: Great tool - i used it but unfortunately couldn't get the data back - even extundelete couldn't get it back. Thanks